# About Scala's syntax

Tags: scala

[Problem picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/np9oD.png)

Can anyone tell me what this means:

```
A = (rs: WrappedResultSet) => throw new IllegalStateException ("The extractor isn't specified yet.")
```

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253896/2988 to understand why "Explain this code to me" questions are off-topic, and what to do to improve your question.

Comment: Doesn't seem that different from a Java function declared to return a result but instead always throws an exception...

Answer (score 1):

```
def fun[A](extractor: WrappedResultSet => A = (rs: WrappedResultSet) => throw new IllegalStateException("The extractor isn't specified yet.")): A
```

It means that method `fun` which takes generic type parameter `A` and a function called extractor of type `WrappedResultSet => A`. If no value of `extractor` is passed to `fun`, then fun uses the default behavior which is to throw `IllegalStateException` as shown in the code above.

Let me know if it helps!!

Comment: `fun` is *not* a function, it is a method.